# Can I snapshot and restore memory of Objective-C object graph?

Tags: objective-c, memory, snapshot

I'm designing a object persistent code.
IMO, memory snapshot is fastest, reliable and compact persistent method within a few limitation.

It's easy with C structs. I can layout all objects' memory layout manually. I can save all references as index of object collection. So reference is not a problem.

Anyway I want to try this with Objective-C objects. To do this, objects must be positioned in specific location of memory. So, if I can specify memory location of allocation, I can snapshot the memory. And when restoring, I can get an object at specific address.

Of course, all of these are machine-specific and needs many tricks, but it's fine to me.
The only problem is I don't know way to specify location of new Objective-C object. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally people use `NSCoding` and `NSKeyedArchiver` (or some custom subclass thereof). I think your C method would have worked before the 64-bit runtime, since the data part of objects was implemented using structs, but I think the new runtime's use of nonfragile instance variables would complicate matters. In any event, the program that loads the persistent objects still has to have the class definitions for them, either hard-coded or loaded via bundles.